# How to copy my .so file in Qt for Android into android-build/libs/arm64-v8a before launching the app in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, android-ndk, qt-creator

I have added my own .so shared library file into Qt project and it generated the following:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib-resources/release/ -lmysofile
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib-resources/debug/ -lmysofile
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib-resources/ -lmysofile

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/lib-resources
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/lib-resources
```

but when I run the app on an Android device it complains about failing to `dlopen`the .so library.

When I navigated to my [build-folder]/android-build/libs/armd64-v8a folder, I did not see "libmysofile.so" in there.

I tried using the following in my .pro to copy the .so but that didn't work either, because it requires a make install before running the app which is considered too late in my case since I am using the Run feature in Qt Creator.

```
copy_lib.files    = $$PWD/lib-resources/libmysofile.so
copy_lib.path     = $$[build-dir]/android-build/libs/arm64-v8a
INSTALLS                  += copy_lib
```

What am I missing? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems indeed you are just missing the "make install" call. Since you are using QtCreator, you can add "install" argument to your build/run process.

Under "Projects" tab, add a custom process "Make" step where you indicate "install" as an argument. If you want it to be done every time you build, use the "Build" section. If you prefer it to be done only at deploy, use "Run" section with "Deployment steps". Note that when you run an app with QtCreator, it basically starts to build, then deploys and finally really run the app.

Comment: is `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += cp $$PWD/lib/mylib.so $$OUT_PWD/android-build/libs/arm64-v8a` a viable option?

Comment: added make install to as custom deploy step. it's complaining that it's Read-only mkdir: `/libs/arm64-v8a/: Read-only file system
make: *** [install_target] Error 1`
Is `$${OUT_PWD}` read-only?

Comment: QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS is an other way to do it, if I remember well you would not need the "install" call with make. But prefer the "make install" as long as possible, it the most standard way.

I do not think it is read-only. Have you checked that your given paths are correct ? Have tried any other output path (like /tmp for instance) just for test purpose ?